# Naming an interface that does something and its opposite

Tags: interfaces, naming

Maybe I'm overthinking about naming, but it's a problem I've encountered several times and it was really annoying every time.

I have three interfaces. The first is IAssembler, which has assemble(...) method. The second is IDisassembler with disassemble(...) method, and the third is [no good name for that one] which inherit from them both. How would you call the last one?

More examples: serializer and diserializer, compiler and decompiler, encrypter and decrypter...

The conventions might change a bit between languages - I mostly use c++/c#.

Comment: Maybe not an answer in and of itself, but very much on point: a codec (e.g. video codec) is named from it being used for **co**ding / **dec**oding. A modem (such as your old 56k modem) is named from it being a device for **mo**dulation / **dem**odulation. Those (once) neologisms were created specifically because there was no good name for them otherwise. If you'd apply the same naming logic in your case, it'd be **as**sembling / **dis**assembling => **asdis** (For your other examples: **sedes**, **comdecom** (because codec is taken), **endec**). Who knows, maybe these will catch on ;)

Comment: Came here to say just this!

Comment: Since you mention c#, .Net has `JsonSerializer` which performs both serialization and deserialization. This isn't 100% intuitive, but in a world with good documentation, good method names, and intellisense, it's not a big challenge. While it makes sense to have a class that can perform an operation and its inverse, I'd hope that the multiple responsibilities of the class were well-divided internally.

Comment: @Flater The most popular Rust serialization library is called [`serde`](https://serde.rs/), using the same naming scheme. (**ser**ialize and **de**serialize)

Comment: It may be worth thinking about *why* you need a separate interface - in what contexts is it necessary to have an object that supports both assembling and disassembling? That may help you craft a descriptive name for the task that the interface will perform.

Comment: Is assembling and disassembling even very different? You're translating from one language to another (ASM vs machine code). I could see how both would have identical interfaces, but one takes (say) source code as a binary array and outputs another binary array with the assembly in it, or whatever data structure you want. Or vice-versa. I understand *internally* they are very different, and may have different "options", but other than that ...

Comment: Serialization implies "data in memory to data in a file" and deserialization the opposite. However, I think for this case, they ARE different, because of the nature of the thing ... so I guess it depends on how you want to expose the interface to the caller. But in the case of "source code" and "compiled file", those are just ... data ... at the input to your assemble or disassemble code right?

Comment: You mention it's an interface. Which code uses that interface? What variable name will it use to refer to such an object? What concrete implementations does the interface have? Most importantly, what are the signatures of the `assemble` and `disassemble` methods - what parameters do they have, but also: what are they doing with the receiver (i.e. the object they're called on)?

Comment: The electronics industry has sort of standardized this: serializer / deserializer = SERDES (used to be called UART but these days a UART is just an 8 bit version of a SERDES), encoder / decoder = CODEC (also used in the software industry), modulator / demodulator = MODEM

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unless it actually reaches a point where for some reason you are using the term every other line, call it `IAssemblerDisassembler`. Clarity is more important than brevity.

Comment: Note that the impact of a name is not only in code, it also impacts verbal and written technical communication (whether informal, analysis, or documentation). I don't disagree with the answer itself, but "using it every other line" is not the sole impact that the chosen name has.

Comment: @Flater Lines certainly exist in written technical communication as well :) but point taken, it's not meant to be taken literally.

Answer (score 9):

Very much on point:

- A codec (e.g. video codec) is named from it being used for **co**ding / **dec**oding.
- A modem (such as your old 56k modem) is named from it being a device for **mo**dulation / **dem**odulation.

Those names, which were neologisms at the time, were created specifically because there was no good name for them otherwise.

If you'd apply the same naming logic in your case, it'd be:

- Assembling / disassembling => **asdis**
- Serialization / deserialization => **sedes**
- Compilation / decompilation => **comdecom** (because codec is already taken)
- Encryption / decryption => **endec**

When no commonly understood name is readily available, it is perfectly fine to create one for yourself (which is exactly what they did for codecs and modems). The only thing you should take care of is to define these neologisms in your dictionary.

I generally advise any codebase to already maintain such a dictionary, so that you can maintain a ubiquitous language between the various stakeholders involved in the project.
Starting from that good practice, the only requirement that flows from creating your own word is to add it to said dictionary.

---

Also, just for the sake of clarity, you don't *have* to form the new word from the initial letters of its constituent parts; but it is a helpful mnemonic that enables people to remember these new words.

You could instead call these four examples a Schmoopsie, Floopsie, Doopsie and Clyde; but that seems like a more confusing name and is therefore not as good.

Deciding on the clearest name is very contextual and can't be put into a singular rule. You have to consider the practicality of using it. Often, these kinds of names tend to form organically during the project's lifetime, as people have to consistently refer to [thing] and slowly start forming a ubiquitously agreed upon name that describes [thing].

This is how most words were formed in human history: long term conversational consensus.

Comment: Also, transceiver.

Comment: A popular Rust package is called [`serde`](https://serde.rs/) from SERialization/DEserialization. Almost exactly like your example!

Comment: @nneonneo Great minds, huh? I just made the same comment on the main post within a minute of your comment.

Comment: @nneonneo Although the proper analogy would be `sedes`.

Comment: A hardware block that does serialization and deserialization is a _serdes_. So yes, very close real-industry examples.

Comment: Serializer / deserializer already exist - they're SERDES and they're widely used by serial hardware like USB, PCIe, HDMI etc.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=serdes